# Beginner Haskell - how to implement this function?

Tags: haskell

This code is taken from https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application

I'm attempting to implement this function :

```
comp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> a -> c)
comp2 f g = (\x y -> g (f x) (f y))
```

using

```
*Main> comp2 3 4
```

but receive exception :

```
<interactive>:19:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that `it' has the inferred type
      it :: forall a b c.
            (Num (a -> b), Num (b -> b -> c)) =>
            a -> a -> c
*Main>
```

How to implement `comp2` function ?

Comment: Note that `comp2 == flip on`, where `on` is defined in `Data.Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you mean implement and not use?
If you look at `comp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> a -> c)`, it is possible to see that comp2 takes two functions, f and g. To use comp2, you need to give it two functions and probably two values. Try this

```
comp2 (*2) (+) 2 3
```

Answer (score 7):

You've *implemented* `comp2` just fine. You just don't *use* it right. The arguments to `comp2` are both functions. Is `3` a function? I daresay not.

Haskell compilers have an extremely open mind though – GHC assumes that `a -> b` *could* possibly have a `Num` instance (which is what's required to use numerical literals). Hence it doesn't give an error like `` Couldn't match type `a -> b` with numerical literal `3` ``, but tries to go on with the assumption that there *must* be such an instance because you are invoking it. But to actually *search* for that instance, the compiler needs to have `FlexibleContexts` enabled.

```
Prelude> comp2 3 4

<interactive>:9:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a b c.
            (Num (a -> b), Num (b -> b -> c)) =>
            a -> a -> c
Prelude> :set -XFlexibleContexts 
Prelude> comp2 3 4

<interactive>:11:1:
    Could not deduce (Num (a -> b0))
    from the context (Num (a -> b), Num (b -> b -> c))
      bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                 (Num (a -> b), Num (b -> b -> c)) => a -> a -> c
      at <interactive>:11:1-9
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a b c.
            (Num (a -> b), Num (b -> b -> c)) =>
            a -> a -> c
    Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

This is still not as clear as we'd like, but it points out the problem: you try to use function types as number types.